# Capturing GPS coordinates on the ground in Boliva?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

Assuming no cellular or internet connection, what is the best way to capture GPS coordinates on the ground in Boliva? Preferably a free approach.  For example, are their any android apps that can do this without a cellular connection?

Comment: Do you want to do this with a cell phone?  Do you not have access to a handheld gps?  Modify your question to reflect data capture methodology.

Comment: I think that the cheapest way is to buy a small GPS receiver (around 200 $)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giscloud.mdc

It works pretty well, accuracy depends on the quality of your phone's GPS reciever.